# Solving recurrence with Maple rsolve

Tags: recurrence-relations, maple

I have a simple recurrence with two variables and cases:

$
f(a,b) =
\begin{cases}
0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~a \leq 0 \\
f(a-1,b)+1~~~~~~              a > b    \\
f(a,b-1)+1~~~~~~              otherwise
\end{cases}
$

I'm trying to use `rsolve` from Maple but I get nothing.
Here is how I encoded it (very primitive, I agree):

```
rsolve({f(-abs(a), b) = 0, f(1 + abs(a), abs(a) - abs(b)) = f(abs(a), abs(a) - abs(b))}, f)
```

Is it possible to solve with Maple? Or any other software??

Comment: Are there any other pre-defined values, except $0$? Why not $\forall a,b\,f(a,b)=0$?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin you are completely right I forgot the `+1` from the recurrence. I fixed it now.

Comment: Seems like $f(a,b)=\lfloor a\rfloor+\lfloor b\rfloor+f(\{a\},\{b\})$ where $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}0&\hbox{if }x=0\\1&\hbox{if }x>y\\2&\hbox{if }0<x\le y\end{cases}$ for $0\le x,y \le 1$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin note that whenever $b<0<a$ then $f(a,b)=a$ ...